# Shinydashboard: create dynamic boxes of checkboxes, filter on all inputs

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Been pulling my hair out over this one for several days. The Shiny app I'm building opens a database which regularly gets updated. As such, values in the columns can change, and I want to make sure the users can filter based on these values. Problem is: the checkboxes need to appear in seperate boxes (for organization purposes).

So, imagine a user sees:

**Severity**

[] CGI

[] GAF

**Alliance**

[]WAI

[]STAR

There's no problem creating these boxes. Initially, I made them all so the selected values were stored in "measures". Problem is: you can't have multiple checkboxGroupInput all sending values to 'measures' (i.e. input$measures) and filter on them (i.e. table_data %>% filter(Measure %in% input$measures).

I solved this issue by giving them all unique inputID's. I.e. input$Severity , input$Alliance . 
I am able to make the filtering work by manually writing: 
table_data %>% filter(Measure %in% input$Alliance| Measure %in% input$Severity)

But the moment I try to make the inputID's that I want to filter on automate, it simply won't work.

For instance:

```
inputslist <- c("input$Alliance", "input$Severity")

table_data %>% filter(Measure %in% inputslist)
```

Does nothing

```
inputslist2 <- c("Measure %in% input$Alliance|Measure %in% input$Severity")

table_data %>% filter(inputslist2)
```

Returns: **Argument 2 filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector**

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to apply a filter on many checkboxgroups?

Comment: checkboxGroupInput will return a character vector if multiple elements are selected: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.4.0/checkboxGroupInput.html. So input$measures should be a character vector of length however many boxes are selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't tell you why, but after having messed around with it endlessly, I figured out this format works:

filterstatement <- paste0("filter(table_data, ",paste0("Measure %in% ",inputslist, collapse="|"),")")

table_data <- as.data.frame(eval(parse(text=filterstatement)))
table_data

---

Even the slightest variation will throw errors. Like if you put the "filter" command outside of the filterstatement , and only put in the list of inputs, it doesn't work.  If you use table_data %>% filter( ... ), it doesn't work. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

`"input$Alliance"` doesn't work because input is a genuine object/variable name, so can't be in quotes. Instead, try `input[['Alliance']]` - this is how you get objects dynamically from a list.

So:

```
inputslist <- c(input[['Alliance']], input[['Severity']])
table_data %>% filter(Measure %in% inputslist)
```

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for thinking along! I've tried to quickly implement my best guess at what you mean, but it doesn't seem to work. For reference, I've tried:
inputslist <- c("input[['Alliance']]")
table_data %>% filter(Measure %in% inputslist)

Comment: You don't want the quotes around input. Try inputslist <- c(input[['Alliance']]) table_data %>% filter(Measure %in% inputslist)

Comment: Hey Matt, 

Thanks so much! That works great! Do you have any suggestions how I can autocreate the inputslist? Say I have a list of 'Alliance', 'Severity', 'Depression'. Any idea how to make it so it writes
inputslist <- c(input[['Alliance']], input[['Severity']], input[['Depression']]) from that list?

Comment: Never done something like that with the input object, but if it's acting like a normal list then something like unlist(input[vector_of_input_names]) should do it.

Comment: That gives: 
"Single-bracket indexing of reactivevalues object is not allowed." 

To reproduce: 
constructslist2 <- c("Alliance","Severity", "Symptoms")
inputslist2 <- unlist(input[constructslist2])

table_data %>% filter(Measure %in% inputslist2)